# How to change value of each html element with a specified class?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of elements, each of them has a `span` element with class `size`, I want to convert each one of them to readable value (bytes => kb, mb, etc.) I'm not sure how to update those values on the page.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/x84733/pen/GGGEzx?editors=1010

```js
function formatBytes(bytes,decimals) {
    if(bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
    var k = 1024,
        dm = decimals || 2,
        sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
        i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}


var size = document.getElementsByClassName("size");


function updateValue(v){
    size.innerHTML = formatBytes(v);
}


for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
    updateValue(size.item(i));
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="size">875</span></li>
  <li><span class="size">25984</span></li>
  <li><span class="size">12525125</span></li>
  <li><span class="size">23234</span></li>
  <li><span class="size">325235</span></li>
  <li><span class="size">0</span></li>
  <li><span class="size"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're passing to `formatBytes` is the `span` element, not its content. You're also trying to set `innerHTML` on `size` (which is an HTMLCollection), not on the element you passed (`v`). Instead:

```
function updateValue(span) {
    span.innerHTML = formatBytes(parseFloat(span.innerHTML));
}
```

Or you might use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) rather than `innerHTML`.

A couple of side notes:

- You can use `size[i]` rather than `size.item(i)`. The old `item` function is a bit archaic.
- You never need to call `parseFloat` on the result of `/`, the result of `/` is *already* always a number.
- Strongly recommend naming variables containing lists, arrays, collections, etc. in the plural. E.g., `sizeSpans` or similar, not `size`.
- If you need to support IE8 (hopefully you don't), it doesn't have `getElementsByClassName` but it does have `querySelectorAll` which is more general-purpose (accepts any valid CSS selector): `var size = document.querySelectorAll(".size")`.
- Similarly, if you need to support IE8, be aware it doesn't have `textContent`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need 
First: pass the position of the item in the list
Second: you apply the method on the item itself but you need to do on the `innerHTML`

```
function updateValue(v, i){
     size.item(i).innerHTML = formatBytes(parseFloat(v.innerHTML));
}
```

```js
        function formatBytes(bytes,decimals) {
            if(bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
            var k = 1024,
                dm = decimals || 2,
                sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
                i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
            return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        }

        
        var size = document.getElementsByClassName("size");


        function updateValue(v, i){
            if(v.innerHTML.length > 0){
            size.item(i).innerHTML = formatBytes(parseFloat(v.innerHTML));
}
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) 
        {
            updateValue(size.item(i), i);
        }
```

```html
        <ul>
          <li><span class="size">875</span></li>
          <li><span class="size">25984</span></li>
          <li><span class="size">12525125</span></li>
          <li><span class="size">23234</span></li>
          <li><span class="size">325235</span></li>
          <li><span class="size">0</span></li>
          <li><span class="size"></span></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I've been search Google for like 10 minutes and couldn't find the way to change value of each html element in a list

Comment: @Un1  as you set value by `.innerHTML` you get the value by `.innerHTML`